# How do i check if element exists by id with Jasmine?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jasmine, protractor

How do i use jasmine to simply check if element exist on the page by id?

I went over the [matchers](http://ngmodules.org/modules/angularjs-jasmine-matchers), `toExist()` not seems to solve this issue.

This is what i tried:

```
1. expect(by.id('my-id')).not.toExist();

2. expect($(document)).not.toContain($(#my-id));
```

can you help?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Using Protractor v1.x (without angularjs-jasmine-matchers):

```
expect(element(by.id('my-id')).isPresent()).toBe(true);
```

Comment: Protractor is a lot of overhead for simple unit tests. @runTarm's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24865352/749181) avoids the excess.

Comment: Getting an error :"error TS2345: Argument of type 'true' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Expected<Promise<boolean>>'."

Comment: Yep, this is a big problem for anyone using protractor in TypeScript.

Answer (score 11):

To use the [angularjs-jasmine-matchers](https://github.com/ferronrsmith/angularjs-jasmine-matchers), you could write the test like this:

```
expect('#my-id').not.toExist();
```